# How to esttab different variable in one row

Tags: stata

I want to `esttab` specific variable in one row

Use data in Stata

```
eststo clear
sysuse auto

eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg
eststo: quietly regress price weight foreign
esttab
```

```
--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
                    price           price   
--------------------------------------------
weight              1.747**         3.321***
                   (2.72)          (8.39)   

mpg                -49.51                   
                  (-0.57)                   

foreign                            3637.0***
                                   (5.44)   

_cons              1946.1         -4942.8***
                   (0.54)         (-3.67)   
--------------------------------------------
N                      74              74   
--------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

What I need is `mpg` and `foreign` result in the same line.
In my data the variable have similar names.
like var_1 var_2 var3

```
--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
                    price           price   
--------------------------------------------
weight              1.747**         3.321***
                   (2.72)          (8.39)   

mpg/foregin        -49.51          3637.0***         
                  (-0.57)          (5.44)         
  

_cons              1946.1         -4942.8***
                   (0.54)         (-3.67)   
--------------------------------------------
N                      74              74   
--------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would typically indicate a covariate that is a ratio of mpg and foreign, which is not what you have. I would avoid doing that since it makes it hard for people to tell what is different about your specifications when they are used to a certain table grammar and could even be perceived as dishonest. It also does not tell you which variable is in which specification.

But it can be done like this:

```
esttab, rename(mpg "mpg or foreign" foreign "mpg or foreign"). esttab, rename(mpg "mpg or foreign" foreign "mpg or foreign")  varwidth(15)  

-----------------------------------------------
                         (1)             (2)   
                       price           price   
-----------------------------------------------
weight                 1.747**         3.321***
                      (2.72)          (8.39)   

mpg or foreign        -49.51          3637.0***
                     (-0.57)          (5.44)   

_cons                 1946.1         -4942.8***
                      (0.54)         (-3.67)   
-----------------------------------------------
N                         74              74   
-----------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```